# Not very helpful callstack when running a mocha test using selenium webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

When running a test in mocha using the selenium webdriver for JavaScript the call-stack it not really helpful.

As a simple example I've used the following simple test script `test.js`:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');

const TIMEOUT = 30000;

test.describe('selenium webdriverjs', function () {
    var driver;

    this.timeout(TIMEOUT);

    test.before(function () {
        driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).build();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    });

    test.after(function () {
        driver.quit();
    });

    test.it('error stack', function () {
        driver.get('http://www.google.com');
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('doesnotexit'));
    });
});
```

that generates the following error stack when (for example) run from Gulp:

```
  selenium webdriverjs
    1) error stack


  0 passing (4s)
  1 failing

  1) selenium webdriverjs error stack:
     NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"doesnotexit"}
      at new bot.Error (...\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
      at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (...\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:109:9)
      at ...\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:379:20
      at promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.invokeCallback_ (.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.
js:1337:14)
      at promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_.execute_ (.../node_modules/selenium-
webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2776:14)
      at promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_ (.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver
/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2758:21)
      at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (...\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
  From: Task: selenium webdriverjs error stack
      at Context.ret (...\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:128:10)
      at callFnAsync (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:306:8)
      at Test.Runnable.run (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:261:7)
      at Runner.runTest (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:421:10)
      at ...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
      at next (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:341:14)
      at ...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:351:7
      at next (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:283:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:319:5)
```

The stack consists of a series of deeply nested function in the `mocha` and `selenium` libraries of the local `node_modules` directory and actual test script `test.js` is not even part of the stack.

I'm wondering, if this is really the best information I can get from this setup if I just did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is really too much unnecessary and not really helpful information with all of the meaningless async traceback cruft, but *the most important part of it, the webdriver error itself, is on top and is pretty self-descriptive*:

> NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"doesnotexit"}

You may try to clean up the output with the help of [`mocha-clean`](https://github.com/rstacruz/mocha-clean) package. When applied, it should really leave the error message itself and only relevant parts of the stack trace eliminating everything `mocha`- and `selenium-webdriver`-specific:

> Mocha stack traces are riddled with frames that you don't want to see,
>   like code from modules and Mocha internals. It strips away mocha
>   internals, node_modules, absolute paths (based on cwd), and other
>   unneccessary cruft.

Comment: In this example file it is easy but in actual production scripts it can take incredibly long to find where the error originates. Is this really the best that this environment can do to help me debugging a script?

Comment: @materialdreams updated the answer, please try `mocha-clean` and see if it's good enough for you.

Comment: I do not really care about the stack frames that mocha-clean can remove but rather really miss any indication of where the error originates in my own code.